# select element is not working in android 5.0 and above with cordova 4.1.1 and ionic version 1.1.1

Tags: jquery, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

After commenting the below codes in ionic.bundle.js select element is working but the view inside ion-nav-view tag is dissappeared.

Waiting for help....

below is the code of ionic.bundle.js

```
    function tapMouseDown(e) { 
  if (e.isIonicTap || tapIgnoreEvent(e)) return null;
  if (tapEnabledTouchEvents) {
    void 0;
    e.stopPropagation();
    alert(e);
    if ((!ionic.tap.isTextInput(e.target) || tapLastTouchTarget !== e.target) && !(/^(select|option)$/i).test(e.target.tagName)) {   
      e.preventDefault();
    }
    return false;
  }
  tapPointerMoved = false;
  tapPointerStart = ionic.tap.pointerCoord(e);
  tapEventListener('mousemove');
  ionic.activator.start(e);
}
```